# HTML tag to prevent HTML tags to be executed?

Tags: html, xhtml

Basic question which I thought of asking on Superuser, but it is a programming question I think.  I just started learning HTML, so please bear with me.

How can I prevent a program from interpreting an HTML tag / syntax?  **For example**, I want to write a flash card like this:

> The html code for `<` is `&lt;`

I would like a solution that would work for any or most syntax, not just for `<`.

How can I enter the syntax (without any space) to make sure the code isn't interpreted?

Comment: I wonder. How can you type less-than simbol without knowing the answer? Should you already know? Or Do I not understand the question?

Comment: I edited the question above.  I'm looking for a solution I could use for any tag.

Comment: @NawaMan: he knows the `&lt;` encoding, not rest of the possible symbols.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are going to have to do it manually.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_4.asp) you have the full encoding table. The most commonly used codes are:

```
Character  Entity Number  Entity Name  Description
"          &#34;          &quot;       quotation mark
'          &#39;          &apos;       apostrophe (does not work in IE)
&          &#38;          &amp;        ampersand
<          &#60;          &lt;         less-than
>          &#62;          &gt;         greater-than
```

Comment: @voyager : Not as easy as inserting two tag if you disable interpretation with JavaScript.

Comment: Unable to edit the answer, the link is broken. Working link : https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_entities_4.asp

Answer (score 10):

This:

```
The html code for &lt; is &amp;lt;
```

Renders as:

The html code for < is &lt;

The basic strategy is to escape the `&` as `&amp;`

Answer (score 7):

In this case, you **DON'T** need to encode it. Try this one:

```
<xmp> html < &lt; </xmp>
```

I'm not sure about cross browsers support, but works on IE7,FF3,Chrome3

Comment: That is a deprecated tag.  Do not use it.

Comment: sure, but solves the problem; he can use xmp or encode his content

Comment: Actually, I think that for any place outside of a web page, that's probably not a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you don't want the entity to be rendered? If you want to display `&lt;` you'll have to  use the entity for the ampersand: `&amp;`.

Answer (score 1):

The html code for < is &lt;

That is, type `&lt; is &amp;lt;`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to server side scripting capabilities, you might be able to use utility functions of that platform. For example, in PHP you might use the `htmlentities` function to your advantage:

```
echo htmlentities("The html code for < is &lt;");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `<pre> &lt; </pre>` sequence

Comment: I think this is the solution I need, i.e., that would work for any tag, correct?  Basically anything written between <pre> and </pre> is treated as dumb text?

Comment: The pre element preserves whitespace, but it doesn't escape tags.

Comment: Nick is correct in it that it doesn't escape tags (which escaped me for a moment :-), so a combination of &lt;pre>, &amp;lt; and &amp;amp; would do the trick for you. The &lt;pre> tags are presented in a fixed spaced font which makes it clear is meant to be a code example.

Comment: @rsp: although it would be more semantically correct to use <code><pre>...</pre></code>: the code tags make it clear that it's code, as opposed to other text where whitespace needs to be preserved, such as poetry. P.S. Isn't it annoying the way SO has different automatic escaping rules in comments to those in answers ;-)

Comment: @NickFitz: xmp element does escape tags;

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode it. For example, '<' = '&lt;'

Here is [the list](http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp).

So in your case it will end up like this:

```
The html code for &lt; is &amp; l t ;
```

Comment: You've linked to the url encodings not the html entities http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html_entities.asp

Comment: What a shame? I will fix that. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
<textarea readonly rows="2" cols="50" style="border:none; color:lightGray; background-color:black;">
<<line1>>
<<line2>>
</textarea>
```

is the only supported option . but its not enabled neither here neither on GitHub .

i'm 5min with HTML, so also would appreciate anyone enhancing it with dynamic size, achieved trough the tag's HTML/CSS attributes, or, if its not possible, trough a small embed Java Script .